# Life cycle/length of a DataSource injected with @Resource annotation

Tags: java, servlets, annotations, jndi

I'm far from an expert of the intricacies of Resource Injection, and of indeed DataSources in Java, but I generally understand the process of doing a lookup for a predefined JNDI resource to get a datasource from.

Using Resource Injection as an alternate method, the below syntax works:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/Foo")
private javax.sql.DataSource con;
```

However, I am using this in a servlet and as such wondering, how long this injected connection object's value will exist? Presumably, as it's simply an object within the servlet, it will inject when the servlet is first instantiated and exist for the same duration as the servlet (assuming I don't manually change it). Is this correct? Or does the servlet re-inject the resource everytime the servlet is used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A servlet container only ever creates one instance of your servlet. The IoC container you're using will then instantiate and inject the `DataSource`, so the value in `con` will remain the same for the life of your servlet, ie. the life of the application.

As to the underlying connection the DataSource is trying to make will, that's up to your datasource.

Comment: Ah, thankyou, it's as I thought. Is this considered good practice? Or should the Resource Injection not generally be used within a servlet?

Comment: @SpAm It's absolutely considered good practice. It doesn't matter where you use it, as long as it serves its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Generally container managed resources are injected using `@Resources` annotation. And container managed resources live as long as the container is running ( unless your are not manually kill it or any exception happens). Several applications can use the same resource object, provided that they live in the same application server ecosystem (same application server or cluster or server domain). But servlets are managed by your applications and lives within the application's scope as long as your application is running! So in terms of life span, if you compare resources are longer living than servlets.

And yes you are right, if you inject resources to a servlet, the reference of the resource will remain from the creation of the servlet to the end of the servlet's life cycle. The injection is not related with, how you are using the servlet or the resource.

Hope, this answers your question, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`it will inject when the servlet is first instantiated and exist for the same duration as the servlet`

Correct.

`Or does the servlet re-inject the resource everytime the servlet is used?`

No, this couldn't be happening because each request is served by a different thread. It wouldn't be good if those threads would modify the fields of the servlet. Request processing methods of the servlet must not modify its fields.